# (Solved) Magento 2.2.2 - Update product price per website programmatically not working

Tags: price, multistore, magento2.2.2, multicurrency

I'm trying to import product prices from an XML file, which contains prices in two different currencies for the same product (EUR and DKK).
I've created a website for each currency and set the "Catalog Price Scope" to "Website".

We also have websites for B2B and B2C, so we use the following website setup:

1. B2B - EUR
2. B2B - DKK
3. B2C - EUR
4. B2C - DKK

The problem is in the code below. In the foreach($storeIds as $storeId) loop, only the first store get updated correctly and the following stores will be set to "Use Default Price". Has anyone experienced something like this?

```
/**
 * Update product price
 * @param $line
 */
private function _updateProduct($sku, $price, $currency) {
    //EUR website store Ids
    $storeIds = $this->moduleHelper->getStoreIdsByCurrency($currency);

    foreach($storeIds as $storeId) {
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, false, $storeId);

            if($product->getId()) {
                if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                    //set price on associated simple products
                    foreach ($product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product) as $_product) {
                        $this->_updateProductPrice($_product, $price, $storeId);
                    }
                } else {
                    //set price on simple product
                    $this->_updateProductPrice($product, $price, $storeId);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
             // Intentionally left empty.
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Update product price for specific store
 * @param $_product
 * @param $price
 * @param $storeId
 * @return bool
 */
private function _updateProductPrice($_product, $price, $storeId) {
    try {
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($_product->getId(),false, $storeId);
        $product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $product->save($product);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Intentionally left empty.
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If I change the array $storeIds to only have one store id, then the product price will be set correctly for that specific website.

---

I've found a working solution using ProductResourceModel instead of ProductRepositoryInterface.

```
/**
 * Update product price for specific store
 * @param int $productId
 * @param string $price
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return bool
 */
private function _updateProductPrice($productId, $storeId, $price) {
    try {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $this->productResourceModel->load($product, $productId);
        $product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should add your solution as answer and mark it accepted instead of updating it to question.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any explanation for why this is happening? I've implemented the same solution by I can't figure why the first solution works